# Where do Mac OS X keep its display settings?

Tags: macos

I'm developing an application and on one machine with Retina display I have a few problems regarding resolution. To debug it I want to have resolution and dpi settings, so, where can I find a configuration file with these settings?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to see the pixel densities of displays, but the resolutions are stored in `~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.windowserver*.plist`. If you have multiple displays, it doesn't tell which display set is active or which is the main display though.

`system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType` only includes the currently active displays.

Comment: Thank you, `system_profiler` is quite helpful. I use 10.8.2 and it looks like I don't have `com.apple.windowserver*` in directory you specified or anywhere else.